# How to union a cube and a cylinder with a bevel

Tags: modeling, modifiers, customization, geometry, bevel

I want to union a cylinder with a cube and achieve a bevel as well.

As seen in the picture. I've tried a simple union and applied a bevel and subsurface but it's causing weird geometry.

Any help will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: If there is weird geometry after bool then it means that you used 2 objects with different vert counts @moonboots down is showing how you need to place 2 objects nicely to align vertices as well and even merge them afterwards. If you do it properly you will have no weird geometry

Answer (score 6):

You can create your shape with a bevel (here 3 segments), then create a cylinder (here 12 vertices):

[image]

Then boolean:

[image]

Bevel the joint, rework a bit to merge some vertices:

[image]

Add some edge loops in otder to sharp the edges:

[image]

You could also use the *Knife Project* tool to cut a circle on the top of your shape, then extrude.